# Enable eth0 and pppoe connection at the same time in ubuntu

Tags: pppoe, dsl

How to keep enable eth0 and pppoe connection at the same time. When i connect my broadband cable in eth0 port, it shows ip detected in eth0 (ifconfig). Now when i connect dsl connection eth0's ip goes away and a new interface added named pppoe with different ip address. How to enable both interface in the same time? Windows can keep both enable at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. I am answering my own question for future reference.

## Steps:

```
1. Connect DSL connection using network manager
2. Connect eth0 interface: sudo udhcpc -i eth0
3. To check current routing: route -n
4. Two interface introduce two default gateway. To access internet remove local  default gateway: sudo route del default gw 172.100.0.1 (for my network)
5. Add routing rule to access ftp servers(172.100.0.0/24 for my network): sudo route add -net 172.100.0.0/24 gw 172.100.0.1 eth0
```

After doing the above steps, `eth0` and `pppoe0` both should have `IP` address.